# Strange behaviour using rows.insert on a seprate thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, datagridview

im creating a simple WinForm app in vb.net that reads in a csv file and displays its contents in a DataGridView component. Below is my code running on the main ui thread.

```
For Each line In fileinput
  Dim elements = line.Split(",")
  DataGridView1.rows.insert(0,elements)
Next
```

The above code works fine on the main form thread. The elements array is used to populate all the cells in each row but if I try the same code on a separate thread all i get in the first cell of each row is System.String[]. Anyone know why this would happen?

Here is the entire code which creates and runs on a new thread:

Dim Filename As String = ""

```
Private Sub BtnCsv_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnCsv.Click

    Opf.ShowDialog()
    Filename = Opf.FileName

    Dim t As Thread
    t = New Thread(AddressOf Me.ParseFileThread)
    t.Start()



End Sub

Public Sub ParseFileThread()

    'RtfOut.Text = Filename

    'Read All Lines From The File since Its a csv
    Dim inputFile() = File.ReadAllLines(Filename)
    'The first line contains the headers for the csv file
    Dim headers() = inputFile(0).Split(",")

    SetGridHeaders(headers)
    SetDataGrid(inputFile)

End Sub

Public Delegate Sub SetGridHeadersDelegate(ByVal headers As Array)

Public Sub SetGridHeaders(ByVal headers As Array)
    If Dgv.InvokeRequired Then
        Dgv.BeginInvoke(New SetGridHeadersDelegate(AddressOf SetGridHeaders), headers)
    Else
        For Each header In headers
            Dgv.Columns.Add(header, header)
            Dgv.Refresh()
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Public Delegate Sub SetDataGridDelegate(ByVal values As Array)

Public Sub SetDataGrid(ByVal values As Array)
    If Dgv.InvokeRequired Then
        Dgv.BeginInvoke(New SetDataGridDelegate(AddressOf SetDataGrid), values)
    Else
        For Each line In values
            Dim cells = line.Split(",")
            Dgv.Rows.Insert(0, cells)
            Dgv.Refresh()
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Me.Invoke(Sub()
          DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, elements)
          End Sub)
```

When you are changing a control on an active UI thread the changes need to occur inside that thread, itself, or you will run into problems.  I'm surprised that the code executed without throwing an exception.

Me.Invoke will make sure the data is populated on the main thread.

Comment: I have already tried that. That's how i got the strange behaviour in the first place. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Okay I take that back. I removed my own thread code and used yours instead and it works perfectly. Thank you so much!